# Anchor Tags in XML

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt

I have an XML file that is displayed in 2 pages. The home page displays the TITLES only of the XML file, the seconds page displays all the XML Items but with Title,Date and Description.

When the Title is clicked from the home page I want it to go to the second page and it goes directly to that ITEM where is rendered as XSLT.

I believe using an anchor is the way but I have no idea how to this with XML.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <generator>Easy Feed Editor</generator>
    <title>RSS Feed</title>
    <description>Welcome to the Site</description>
    <link>www.website.com</link>
    <image><url>http://www.website.com/images/logo2.jpg</url><title> RSS Feed</title>           
    <link>www.website.com</link></image>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <pubDate>Tue, 20 May 2014 13:39:17 GMT</pubDate>
    <managingEditor>TCPC</managingEditor>

    <item>
      <title>NEW YEAR'S DAY
      </title>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[<p>
                 We will resume regular business hours on Thursday, January 2, 2014. </p>
        ]]></description>
        <link>http://www.website.com/PT/news.aspx</link>
        <author>PC</author>
        <guid  isPermaLink="false">0d8a3208-0900-45ad-84f4-4934a751aac3</guid>
        <pubDate>Tue, 20 May 2014 13:38:21 GMT</pubDate>
        <enclosure url="http://www.website.com/images/logo2.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="16645" />
    </item>

    <item>
      <title>SAVE BIG</title>
      <description><![CDATA[<p>
      Pay big description goes here. Sample text. </p>
      ]]></description>
      <link>http://www.website.com/PT/news.aspx</link>
      <author>PC</author>
      <guid  isPermaLink="false">4428636c-218d-46d3-98bd-52e83e27e02f</guid>
      <pubDate>Mon, 16 Dec 2013 13:40:26 GMT</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="http://www.website.com/images/logo2.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="16645" />
    </item>

    <item>
      <title>NEW OFFICE</title>
      <description><![CDATA[<p>
      Office Description</p>
      ]]></description>
      <link>http://www.website.com/PT/news.aspx</link>
      <author>PC</author>
      <guid  isPermaLink="false">45a6ca63-8bad-4b60-bd0a-69190089b789</guid>
      <pubDate>Fri, 06 Dec 2013 21:34:49 GMT</pubDate>
      <enclosure url="http://www.website.com/images/logo2.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="16645" />
    </item>

  </channel>
</rss>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>      
      <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">
        <div style="background-color:#a61f2e;color:white;padding:4px; padding-left:1em;">
          <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 1.5em;">
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
          </span>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em; margin-right:1em;">
          <br></br>
          <h5 style="font-style:italic">
            <xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
          </h5>
          <br></br>
          <p>
            <span style ="font: normal 14px/1.5 'Segoe UI'">
              <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>     
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The anchors and hyperlinks will be part of the target HTML, you do not really encode this into your XML. The XML simply serves as a source for the XSLT to generate them.

To achieve your goal you will have to iterate over your items twice: once to generate the first page with hyperlinks and a second time for the second page with named anchors. You can use the `generate-id()` function to generate a unique id for the anchors. The following XSLT tries to mimic this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>      
      <H1>page1</H1>
      <UL>
        <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">

          <!-- generate a hyperlink to a named anchor on the same page -->
          <LI><A HREF="#{generate-id()}"><xsl:value-of select="title"/></A></LI>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </UL>

      <H1>page2</H1>
        <xsl:for-each select="rss/channel/item">

          <!-- {{{{{ generate a named anchor using the same id -->
          <A NAME="{generate-id()}">
            <div style="background-color:#a61f2e;color:white;padding:4px; padding-left:1em;">
              <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 1.5em;">
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
              </span>
            </div>
          </A>
          <!-- }}}}} -->

          <div style="margin-left:20px;margin-bottom:1em; margin-right:1em;">
            <br></br>
            <h5 style="font-style:italic">
              <xsl:value-of select="pubDate"/>
            </h5>
            <br></br>
            <p>
              <span style ="font: normal 14px/1.5 'Segoe UI'">
                <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```